# Can a university project be turned into a publication?

Tags: publications

I am a Control engineering student and I am actually pursuing a Master's degree in this field. In my academic career I am often involved in projects which can be about optimal control, reinforcement learning and robotics.

In my future I am thinking about applying for a Phd in this field, and in order to be more prepared I would like to ask if it is possible in some way to organize these projects in such a way that I could come out with a research paper from it and try to make a publication.

I have heard of students that have done something similar, but just corridor voices to be honest.

I know it may sound like a naive question, since I am still a student, but could it be possible to do something similar?

And if yes, how should I organize my project?

I know that writing a research paper is really hard, so I am not saying that it is easy, but I am curious about this.

Comment: The pivot question is, have you done something original? You might get some helpful evaluation of that from a prof who is familiar with this work.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, but it depends on whether you meet the standard for publication. Your first stop should be with an advisor or trusted faculty member in the field who has published and who can give you some advice. Probably better advice than you can get here on the specifics.

You also need to read a bit in the literature of your field to see what has been done recently and how it is presented. That is a valuable skill for any aspiring doctoral students. Existing papers will give you an idea about organization. The general plan, of course, is motivation, hypothesis, methodology, execution, results, significance.

The standards of most journals will involve novelty of your results, given that they are correct. How do the results contribute to the literature? How do they enable further work? What important problems do they solve?

But even if you don't reach the standard of having something publishable, it is still a valuable exercise to put your work into a form that is transferrable beyond your coursework.

A professor might also be able to suggest an extension to the required work that does get you up to the level of something that the wider world wants to see. Moreover, establishing such a working relationship with a professor is valuable e in its own right when it comes time to apply to doctoral programs. And perhaps beyond.